# System net web exception when the system is connected for a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a asp.net application connecting to a .net web service, whenever i login & reach the main page, web services returns me back the data.

But if i login for may be more than 1 or 2hrs, when i click any of the links i get:

```
"System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"
```

What is the fix for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because your session gets expired. You will have to check whether the user is still connected to the webserver hosting webservice or not before making any call to that server.

Comment: There is no session concept, i don't check for sessions.

Comment: one way to get that message is if you are supposing you are connected already (as in a session) instead of always connect to the service before each call so the answer above is valid